# How to build models (ODM) in nodejs to use with nedb

Tags: node.js, express, orm, nedb, nosql

I am looking for a ODM module that can be used with [Nedb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nedb) in NodeJs-Express. Is it somehow possible to use [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) or [Waterline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline) schemas in combination with nedb for validation? Mongoose and Waterline do not provide an official adapter for nedb.

At the moment have very low requirements for performance and i am working on a project for the raspberry pi therefore i would like to stick with nedb (or similar file-based nosql database).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Camo](https://github.com/scottwrobinson/camo) is an ODM for nedb and MongoDB, on Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to try it, but there is an adapter for Nedb for waterline that looks like it is dependent from building a Sails application.

It's available at: https://github.com/adityamukho/sails-nedb

EDIT: Sorry, I was incorrect, I was assuming this would work without sails, but I think this [blog](http://adityamukho.com/blog/2014/04/17/an-nedb-adapter-for-sails-waterline-0-10-x/#.VcLIj5NVhBc) from the creator might prove that wrong